# Capture shell output after running python script that raised Exception

Tags: python, bash, shell, groovy

I am running a shell in groovy, that executes a python script. I was able to get the out put of the python script by assigning it to a variable.
However, i would like to capture Exceptions as well, but in case of exception i am unable to get the python trace.
the groovy script:

```
script{
       try{
             var_name = bash("""python3 some_script.py""")
             echo "$(var_name)"
           }
       catch(exc){
            echo "$(var_name)"
                  }
       }
```

in case of no exception raised from python, output from script is printed, but in case of exception in prints null.
any solutions?

Comment: Is the python script writing the python trace to standard err?

Comment: i believe to stdout... if i run it in bash, exception is printed to console

Comment: "i believe to stdout...  if i run it in bash, exception is printed to console" - Stderr by default would be routed to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python writes exceptions to standard error, hence if you want to capture them along with the normal output, you should redirect stderr to stdout by adding `2>&1` to the bash input.

In your case it would be `bash("""python3 some_script.py 2>&1""")`.

I assume the `bash` function sends the argument to the bash shell.